# How can I achieve a stylish vertical menu in WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I'm new to WPF and I've been tasked with creating a UI and I was told it needs to be 'sexy'.

My first task is to createa menu structure for the various options I need to make available to the user. I'd like to do something like this, taken from http://www.wpftutorial.net :

[image]

Unfortunately I don't see any examples on that site of how to implement a vertical menu with sub-menus that have the glassy look and feel.

I'm hoping to achieve the same level of 'sexy' (<-- my bosses term, not mine), but the style doesn't need to be exactly the same.

What steps do I need to take to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The 'sexy' layout you showed, is actually quite outdated (glossy is so 2008-2010...).
Anyway, if you don't go for 3rd parties, here is what this is:

- The container is a [Me](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menu.aspx)[nu](http://wpftutorial.net/Menus.html)
- Each item is a [MenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.aspx)
- Some MenuItems contain their own MenuItems (that's the horizontal dropdown you see)
- Menu and MenuItem seem to have a custom Template/Style/[ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It can indeed be quite some work for someone new to WPF, but you'll definitely learn a lot, however it'll take you several weeks to get it right with no experience.

HTH,

Bab.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to go with 3rd party controls.
DevExpress and Telerik offer some very good WPF controls.

This will save you a lot of time as they have built-in themes and are really good looking.

Trying to do this yourself will probably cost you more in the long run.

You could even download the trial versions and show your boss a demo of the app.